# Configuring nginx and docker on EC2 (Jetbrains)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, teamcity

I have setup Jetbrains Upsource and Teamcity on the same EC2 instance for evalution purposes. If I expose each container on port 80 seperately, I can reach it from the outside world. I want to know how to setup nginx so that I can reach each container over a subdomain like eg. "upsource.example.aws.com" and "teamcity.example.aws.com". I exposed the containers on ports 8080 and 8111 to the host. Is it even possible to achieve this ? If so, I dont know how to start. I read on ways to host multiple domains on one machine for a node web app though exposing the static context. But i have no idea how to make it work with the preconfigured docker images.

- Can this be achieved via nginx conf file ?
- If not, do I have to use two instances or is there another possibility within aws ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible with nginx. You have to use something called [reverse proxy](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/). 
You can expose both the containers in different ports and redirect to these with the help of the nginx configuration.

For example if you have some containers running in port 8000 and 8001 in 127.0.0.1 you can redirect like this:

```
    location /1 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}

   location /2 {
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
}
```

**Updated Answer**

You need to have 3 containers. The nginx server should be running in port 80. The other two containers will host the sites in say port `8000` (upsource.example.aws.com) and port `8111`(teamcity.example.aws.com).

Update the configuration file with the location settings as shown above. Make sure that `location /` forwards to port 8000 and `location /teamcity` forwards to port 8111 in your host. More details on how to configure [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) is on the docker hub.

**Working**
When you go to `blabla.com` the nginx sever forwards it to port 8000 and when you go to `blabla.com/teamcity` its goes to port 8111.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what i was looking for in general. Could you explain how to link those to subdomains when we assume my ec2 instance is reachable under "blabla.com" ?